# Transfer from Khaosan Rd to Suvarnabhumi Airport, Bangkok

Tags: airport-transfer, bkk

I want to know how to get Suvarnabhumi Airport from Khaosan Road. I am staying in D&D Inn. My flight is at 9pm.

What time should I plan to leave from Khaosan Road?

What is the cheapest and best way to get to the airport?

Any idea about the bus service and how much would it charge?

Answer (score 4):

Cheapest is bus / train combo, take the 556 bus to Makkasan Station, then the Airport Rail Link to Suvarnabhumi.  About 35 baht each part.

I don't use the train, so can't really advise on how much time to allow for traveling that way.

Comment: The rail link is perfect, air conditioned too.

Answer (score 2):

I would take bus 15 from Rajdamnoen Avenue to Siam Square.  At Siam Square, get on the Skytrain and go 2 stops to Phayathai Station.  Then switch to the Airport Rail Link.

Link for bus route:  [Bus 15](http://www.transitbangkok.com/lines/bangkok-bus-line/15)

This would cost not more than 100 baht total and might take 2 hours or so, depending on traffic.  A taxi to Phayathai instead of the bus/Skytrain might cost you 70 baht, again depending on traffic.

Answer (score 0):

When I was staying there a few months ago, I just booked a shuttle bus in one of the many travel agencies all over town. I think the price was 100-200 baht and they pick you up from your Inn, so you don't have to worry about anything.

Just make sure you take one on time.